# Interesting PDE $D^3=\mathbf 0$: a generalization of conic curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, recreational-mathematics, conic-sections, tensors

We are all familiar with conic curve in high school but what is a conic curve in higher dimensions?

Here is my guess: consider the simplest third order PDE: $D^3f=\mathbf 0$

This means $f_{i_1i_2i_3}dx^{i_1}\otimes dx^{i_2}\otimes dx^{i_3}= \bf 0$

When $f$ is a two-variable function, the conic curve is a solution: $f=Ax^2+By^2+Cx+Dy+E+Fxy$.

When $f$ is $n$-variable function, is it true that (the subset of the solution): $f=e+\sum_{i,j\in{1,...n}}a_{i,j}x_{i}x_j+\sum_nc_nx$ is a reasonable generalization of conic curve?

Comment: what happened to xy?

Comment: I'd rather call that a (generalised) [quadric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric).